# How to get a static generator starting from a synchronous one?

Tags: generator, solar-energy, synchronous, power-grid, static

I want to model a static generator (a photovoltaic one) inside a simulation tool. This simulation tool has no static generator (it is quite new and not user friendly).
My idea was to model a synchronous generator as static. The first things that came to my mind are:

1. set inertia constant H=0;
2. eliminate exciters/PSS/governor;
3. set all the transient and sub-transient reactances/time constants to 0
4. eliminate any damping
5. set the power factor to 1
6. model the stator resistance and the stator reactance as the equivalent resistance and reactance of a PV plant (including the inverter)

Is this a good way to get an equivalent approximated model of a static generator? Are there any other parameters to consider in order to get a more accurate model?
(I want to specify that this static generator will work always in normal state, just some frequency transient will be tested on the grid).

Comment: By "static generator" do you mean a PV grid tie inverter?

Comment: @user_1818839 sorry you are rigth, I mean a PV plant, so PV panels + inverters (no transformer)

Comment: For small inverters you might look at G83/2 (1 phase) or G59 (3 phase) for UK practice; or the equivalent in your region. They cover frequency, tolerances, harmonics etc. For big inverters ... ask the manufacturer? With batteries, you can program it to mimic any inertia/damping you like to assist grid stability https://hornsdalepowerreserve.com.au/ but I don't know the capabilities of PV-only systems.

Comment: Related : some of the links may contain relevant content... https://cleantechnica.com/2022/06/05/renewables-become-leader-in-grid-resilience-decentralized-approach-to-disaster-recovery/

Comment: "In a virtual synchronous machine, the underlying machine model parameters dictate its dynamic response. In particular, the damping, inertia, and flux-linkage parameters are virtual and can be tuned (Beck and Hesse 2007; Alatrash et al. 2012; Zhong 2016). Although the response of a virtual synchronous machine is similar to that of an actual machine, its time constants can be compressed. " (p.16, https://www.nrel.gov/docs/fy21osti/73476.pdf ). So what you are suggesting (0 inertia etc) may be appropriate for a "grid following" inverter but not for a "grid forming" inverter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you model the inverter-based generation depends on what you want to understand from the model and what part of its behavior you need to represent. In terms of the parameters you describe:

1. *set inertia constant H=0;*  Yes, or a small value if the simulation software won't take a value or zero.
2. *eliminate exciters/PSS/governor;*  Yes.
3. *set all the transient and sub-transient reactances/time constants to 0*  Instead of setting the time constants to zero, you can set the reactances equal to each other.
4. *eliminate any damping* Yes
5. *set the power factor to 1* Yes, assuming that's how the plant operates.
6. *model the stator resistance and the stator reactance as the equivalent resistance and reactance of a PV plant (including the inverter)* This is probably the best you can do with this type of model. Inverter-based generation is generally current-limited, so any impedance value will not be correct. This will only be a problem if you simulate a short-circuit fault close to the generator. Modeling for short-circuit behavior is the most problematic. ([A short presentation of the modeling issues](https://www.nerc.com/comm/PC/Power%20Plant%20Modeling%20and%20Verification%20Task%20Force/NERC_PPMVTF_Nov6-2018.pdf))